# VirtueMart: сбрасывается меню после сортировки товара

Tags: virtuemart, joomla, php, javascript

Доброго времени суток.

VirtueMart 1.1.9. Проблема в том, что когда на странице товаров я начинаю сортировать товар (не важно, по названию или цене), то текущее положение в меню скидывается. Скажите, в какую сторону капать?

Answer (score 1):

Решено.
незнаю было ли подобное у других но в browse_orderbyform.tpl.php обнаружил вот такую строчку

```
<input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="">
```

возможно конечно кто-то до меня правил скрипт, но лишним не будет отписать тут что так делать не стоит, следует указывать так

```
<input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="getShopItemid() ?>" />
```